# Raft algorithm ,prevent term increase

Tags: etcd, raft

In the Raft algorithm, the term is always increasing. Is there any good way to solve this problem and prevent the term from reaching the limit in the future? Because I use a term of type tinyint and I don't want to modify the type, there will be a round of elections in a minute, so the term will grow rapidly.

```
d.Log.Term(d.Log.Term() + 1)
d.Log.State(BeCandidate)
```

I want to modify term=0 after the follower receives the heartbeat, but this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
max(uint64) = 18446744073709551615
one year  =525600 (minute)
so :
max(uint64) / one year = 35096545041304.32(year)
i should worry about it
```

Comment: Could you explain your solution?

Comment: We don't have to worry about reaching the limit. According to my calculation formula, this can run for many years.